# Typecast fails when visual studio extension uses reference to older assembly

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, envdte, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-sdk

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension that references the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine` assembly.

Now I'm trying to cast from `EnvDTE.Project` to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine.VCProject` like this:

`VCProject vcProject = project.Object as VCProject;`

This cast works fine when building and running my extension in Visual Studio 2015 while using the version `14.0` of the VCProjectEngine assembly. However the cast fails when I'm changing the version to `12.0` so that my extension can be installed to VS2013 as well. There must be something I'm missing here.

How can I reference the VCProjectEngine assembly so that my typecast works in VS2013 and VS2015?

Comment: Do you use the Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine.dll reference shipped with VS 2013 under Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies? What I know that this assembly really has different versions for different VS versions, and other community members also got the compatibility issue before:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d82a07ed-a3b9-4321-abb0-a72cb78f9c6e/vcprojectengine-for-different-vs-versions?forum=vsx, it means that certain object type was changed in the higher version. If possible, I suggest you create a new one in VS2013.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT: Thanks for that pointer. Yes, I tried to use the assembly shipped with VS2013. In that case the typecast fails when running the extension in VS2015 but when I install the same extension to VS2013 and run it there everything works out fine.

What do you mean by _"I suggest you create a new one in VS2013"_?

Comment: Just ignore it, actually I mean that if the extension has the compatibility issue in different VS versions, create separate project would be better. Just to make this issue clearly, this issue has been resolved in VS2013 after you use the correct assembly now? am I right? If so, I will post that solution as the answer:)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Building different extensions for each version of VS that reference the respective assembly works. If you post your answer, please also include this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d47bfe90-19bb-4c0c-9f36-74ff60eb490d/vcproject-interface-targeting-multiple-versions?forum=vsx It explains strategies to solve these issues in detail.

Comment: Edit the answer, have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assembly really has different versions for different VS versions，each version of VS need to reference the respective assembly.

Reference:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d47bfe90-19bb-4c0c-9f36-74ff60eb490d/vcproject-interface-targeting-multiple-versions?forum=vsx